# How to get always @* block executed all the time when it's not taking any input from outside(testbench)

Tags: verilog

My code is as follows:

```
module command_FSM(sys_R_Wn,sys_ADSn,,cState,.....);
  input sys_R_Wn;
  input sys_ADSn;
  output  [4:0] cState;

initial
begin
  cState=c_idle;
end

always @*
begin
  if (sys_INIT_DONE==1'b1)
    if(~sys_REF_REQ && ~sys_ADSn)
    begin
      case (cState)
        5'b10000: begin
            cState=c_ACTIVE;
            #10;
        end
        5'b10110:
          if(sys_R_Wn)
          begin 
            cState=c_tRCD;
            #10;
            cState=c_REDA;
          end
          else
          begin
            cState=c_tRCD;
            #10;
            cState=c_WRITEA;
          end
        5'b11000: cState=c_cl;
        5'b10101: cState=c_rdata;
        5'b11010: cState=c_wdata;
        5'b10111: cState=c_tDAL;
      endcase
    end
  end
  endmodule
```

I am not getting this always @* block executed forever and only once the value of cstate is updated, other values of cstate are not used. Should I use assign statement instead of case statement for cstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

always@* is a combinational block. The basic block of any fsm goes like this.

There are three blocks. Two combinational and one sequential. Two states, one next_state and the other current_state. Current_state is always update on clock event because that's when you move from one state to other. Hence, it should be output of a flop. The input to the flop should be next_state.

Now next_state is assigned using a combinational logic which takes input of current_state and external input (in case of mealy).

The second combinational logic will be for output state and that can simply be an assign statement for the given condition.